# Test item type of a container in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to write some Kotlin wrapper around Android SharedPreferences and I'm having this code right now:

```
class KPreferences(ctx: Context) {
    val prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences(ctx.getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun put(key: String, value: Any): Boolean {
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        when (value) {
            is Boolean -> editor.putBoolean(key, value)
            is Float -> editor.putFloat(key, value)
            is Int -> editor.putInt(key, value)
            is Long -> editor.putLong(key, value)
            is String -> editor.putString(key, value)
            is Set<*> -> editor.putStringSet(key, value as Set<String>)
        }
        return editor.commit()
    }
```

This compiles but I can't help searching if I can't make this better by being sure that the Set contains only String and no other type.

I tried this:

```
fun put(key: String, value: Any): Boolean {
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        when (value) {
            is Boolean -> editor.putBoolean(key, value)
            is Float -> editor.putFloat(key, value)
            is Int -> editor.putInt(key, value)
            is Long -> editor.putLong(key, value)
            is String -> editor.putString(key, value)
            is Set<*> ->
                if (value.isEmpty() || value.iterator().next() is String) {
                    editor.putStringSet(key, value as Set<String>)
                }
        }
        return editor.commit()
    }
```

But it seems so inelegant.

The other approach would be defining

```
fun put(key: String, value: Set<String>)
```

and remove the last case in my attempt. I'm just wondering if I'm missing any elegant solution here.

Thanks!

Comment: please add the `Android` tag to your question

Comment: I do not agree because the question was really about Kotlin type checking. I appears I encounter it in an android development but it is a coincidence. Anyway I add the tag to make you happy :)

Comment: or remove the references to Android, and the Android code simplifying the whole thing to just the relevant part.  :-)  either way makes me happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to note that the check you have in the example may not guarantee you from putting a set of something other than string into your editor: if the editor implementation does not copy the set upon putting it, one could pass in an empty set and then later add something other than a string to it:

```
val set = HashSet<Int>()
prefs.put("...", set) // set is empty, the check lets it through
set.add(1)
```

Generic type information is not reified, so you'll need to either introduce overloads for every type you support: `Boolean`, `Float` etc, and `Set<String>`, or go for no proper checking at all

Comment: I was trying to do something like Scaloid Preferences (https://github.com/pocorall/scaloid/blob/master/scaloid-common/src/main/scala/org/scaloid/common/preferences.scala) but re reading it shows me that Set of String is not managed either.

Thank you for the analysis!

Answer (score 0):

I've already made a similar library and it's stable. You can use it if you want: [KPreferences](https://github.com/mohamad-amin/KPreferences)
It uses a completely similar approach.